# How to number node-tags

Tags: xslt

In this (example)xml i need to number the book-tags like `<book1>`, `<book2>` etc.

The resulting XML will be imported and therefore needs that notation. The result will never have more then 6 book-nodes. The xslt i've writen names all `<book>`

This is the original xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book>
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    </book>
   <book>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

This is the xsl i already have:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="catalog">
        <catalog>
            <xsl:if test="//book[author='Corets, Eva']">
                <book>
                    <sample>Here comes info about Eva Corets</sample>
                </book>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="//book[author='Ralls, Kim']">
                <book>
                    <sample>Here comes info about Kim Ralls</sample>
                </book>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="//book[author='Thurman, Paula']">
                <book>
                    <sample>Here comes info about Paula Thurman</sample>
                </book>
            </xsl:if>
        </catalog>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <book>
    <sample>Here comes info about Eva Corets</sample>
  </book>
  <book>
    <sample>Here comes info about Kim Ralls</sample>
  </book>
  <book>
    <sample>Here comes info about Paula Thurman</sample>
  </book>
</catalog>
```

This what i need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <book1>
    <sample>Here comes info about Eva Corets</sample>
  </book1>
  <book2>
    <sample>Here comes info about Kim Ralls</sample>
  </book2>
  <book3>
    <sample>Here comes info about Paula Thurman</sample>
  </book3>
</catalog>
```

Comment: Can you confirm you can definitely use XSLT 2.0? I know the version of the stylesheet says `version="2.0"` but you would still need a compatible XSLT processor to use any XSLT 2.0 features. Thanks!

Comment: Thats a good point. My production envirionment is still on xslt 1.0. SO i'm afraid i'me stuck to that.

Comment: Can you clarify the logic about the authors, please. Why do you want those 3 authors, and not any others? Is the order of the authors important too (i.e. Did you actually just want them in alphabetical order)?. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this should do it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="catalog">
        <catalog>
            <xsl:for-each select="book[author='Corets, Eva']">
            <xsl:variable name="book_el" select="concat('book', position())"></xsl:variable>
               <xsl:element name="{$book_el}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </catalog>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Ed, 
Thanks for your quick respons, it works fine :-)
But i'm afraid that my sample xslt didn't reflect the real sitiuation like it should. I've changed the xslt and output to be like the real situation. Main difference is that i can't use the for-each...

Answer (score 0):

If you can only use XSLT 1.0, then you can make use of a technique call [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to get the distinct authors from the books, although you would need extra work to get them in a specific order.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="books" match="book" use="author" />

  <xsl:param name="authors">|Corets, Eva|Ralls, Kim|Thurman, Paula|</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="catalog">
    <catalog>
      <xsl:for-each select="book[contains($authors, concat('|', author, '|'))][generate-id() = generate-id(key('books', author)[1])]">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($authors, concat('|', author, '|')))" />
        <xsl:element name="book{position()}">
          <sample>
            <xsl:text>Here comes info about </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="author" />
          </sample>
          <info>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('books', author)">
              <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
              <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            </xsl:for-each>
          </info>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </catalog>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could replace the `xsl:sort` with `<xsl:sort select="author" />` if you just wanted them alphabetically listed.